# When I print an array it prints as empty, but it contains items

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase

When I attempt to print an array declared in one file from another file it says the array is empty. I've added code to return the value asynchronously, but it doesn't work.

My first file with the array declaration and the functions I call from the other looks like this:

```
class SearchManager {

var searchResults = [String]()
var listOfMosaics = [String]()

// Retrieves company list from Firebase
func getMosaicTitles(completionHandler: @escaping (_ mosaics: [String]) -> ()) {
    Database.database().reference().child("mosaics").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let allMosaics = snapshot.value as? [String] else {
            print("unable to unwrapp datasnapshot")
            return
        }
        completionHandler(allMosaics)
    })
}

// takes list of all mosaics and filters based on search text
func filterAllMosaics(searchText: String) {
    searchResults = listOfMosaics.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }

}

// resets search results array
func resetSearch() {
    searchResults = []
}
```

}

In the AppDelegate I call the function and try to handle it asynchronously but it still doesn't seem to work:

```
searchManager.getMosaicTitles { (results) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.searchManager.listOfMosaics = results
        }
    }
```

And then in my file backing the tableView controller I have I try to do this:

```
extension SearchResultsTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchManager.resetSearch()
    searchManager.filterAllMosaics(searchText: searchBar.text!)
    tableView.reloadData()
    print(searchManager.listOfMosaics)
    print(searchManager.searchResults)
    }
}
```

When I run the app it prints the above arrays as if they are empty, and obviously doesn't reload the tableView with the correct items for each cell.

Thank you in advanced. This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: does retrieveMosaicTitles return the expected results? what is the value of allMosaicTitles?

Comment: Where exactly do you observe that the arrays have entries? – Is this another variation of the "this is an *asynchronous* request" topic?

Comment: @MartinR I don't believe this is related to asynchronous requests. I've verified that the arrays have entries by adding a print(listOfMosaics) to the retrieveMosaicsTitles()

Comment: Where exactly? Inside the `observe(...)` closure or outside?

Comment: Inside below the self.listOfMosaics = allMosaicTitles

Comment: `observe()` is an *asynchronous* method. It returns immediately, and calls the closure *later,* when the request has been completed.

Comment: So what do I need to add. Do I need to add notifications for when the request is finished?

Comment: Search for "how to return value from asynchronous request" and "completion hander" ...

Comment: @MartinR I've updated my question to handle the asynchronous request but it still doesn't seem to work. What have I done wrong.